# Association attributes in a Django one-to-many foreignkey relationship

Tags: django, attributes, foreign-keys, relationship, manytomanyfield

I would like to model a relationship between a Story class and a Series class.
(I.e. a trilogy of novels)
The relationship is a "one to many" (a series can contain many Stories but a Story can only be part of one Series).
Model-wise this could simply be solved by a foreign key on Story,

> ```
> part_of = models.ForeignKey(Series
>                             , on_delete=models.CASCADE
>                             , related_name='contains_story')
> ```

But I would like a sequence number as an attribute of this relationship.
i.e. (1:The long Earth, 2:The long war, 3:The long Mars, ...). 
I could make it an attribute of Story but that's not clean, a Story not part of a Series should not have a sequence number.

In a "many-to-many" this can be solved using the "through" option. 
by specifying a class and adding attributes to that class.

> ```
> part_of = models.ManyToManyField(Series, through='SeriesPart')
> ```

But "part of a series" is not a "many-to-many" relationship and I want to avoid modelling it like this and having to restrict it in code, so how should I solve this best?

Comment: I'm not sure about your use case but sounds like foreignkey is the way, but I don't understand why you don't want to have a serial number on `Story`.

Comment: it is not a serial number it is its order in a sequence. And a story not part of a sequence should not have that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your objection makes much sense. The reason why you might store an extra attribute on the through table of a many-to-many relationship is precisely because each side of the relationship can have multiple items, and the attribute value is only relevant to one specific combination. (In the case of the [example in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany), John was in the Quarrymen before he was in the Beatles, so there are separate `joined_date` values for John<->Quarrymen, John<->Beatles, and Paul<->Beatles.)

In your case, a story can only be part of one series. There is no other position for The Long Earth other than as part 1 of the Pratchett/Baxter series; it can't simultaneously be part 1 of that but also part 2 of something else. So there's no reason not to store the series number on the story model itself. Stories that are not part of a series can simply leave that blank, just like they leave the FK to Series blank.

Comment: That woks but it is not the cleanest of models. Now I did the following.

`class SeriesPart(models.Model):`
'    series = models.ForeignKey(Series, on_delete=models.CASCADE)'
'    story = models.ForeignKey(Story, on_delete=models.CASCADE)'
'    sequence = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()'